# Can we declare a variable in TestRunner and pass it as parameter to the feature files in karate?

Tags: karate

Is there a way or a method available where we can declare a variable in TestRunner class and pass that as a parameter to the feature files and utilize that parameter in feature file?

Comment: not directly. but see linked answer, you can get values out of the environment and you can see an example here: https://github.com/karatelabs/karate/blob/v1.2.1.RC1/karate-core/src/test/java/com/intuit/karate/core/parallel/ParallelTest.java#L34